# Not updating useState() custom hook when I use setState(somedata)

Tags: reactjs, setstate, react-custom-hooks

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnYmI.jpg)

```
import React from "react";
import useUsersData from "./useUsersData";

export const User = ({ _id, name, age, email }) => {
const [userData, setUserData] = useUsersData();

const handleDelete = (id) => {
const proceed = window.confirm("Are you sure?");
if (proceed) {
  const url = `http://localhost:5000/users/${id}`;

  fetch(url, {
    method: "DELETE",
  })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
    }); }
const remaining = userData.filter((userData) => userData._id !== id);
console.log(userData);
console.log(remaining);
setUserData(remaining);
console.log(userData);
 };

 return (

    <p onClick={() => handleDelete(_id)}>
    X
  </p>
  </div>
  );
 };
```

**the custom hook:**

```
 import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

   const useUsersData = () => {
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState([]);

 useEffect(() => {
  fetch("http://localhost:5000/users")
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((data) => setUserData(data));
  }, []);

 return [userData, setUserData];
 };

 export default useUsersData;
```

not updating **`useState()`** custom hook when I use **`setState(somedata)`** the custom hook **`useState`** does not get updated. I don't know what I did wrong.

You can see in the console log that set user data is not changing.
here is a screenshot
[console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWgy4.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you call the dispatch function of `useState`, its effects on the state will only be noticeable on the next function call.

So if you `console.log` or otherwise try to use the state immediately after a dispatch, it will not have the latest data.

If you want to use the latest state as soon as it is updated, you need to `useEffect` while passing the state in the dependency array.

```js
const Example = () => {
  const [userData, setUserData] = React.useState(['1', '2', '3']);

  const handleDelete = () => {
    const remaining = userData.filter((id) => id !== '3');
    console.log(userData); // will print ['1', '2', '3']
    console.log(remaining); // will print ['1', '2']
    setUserData(remaining);
    console.log(userData); // will still print ['1', '2', '3']
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log('useEffect', userData); // will print "useEffect ['1', '2']"
  }, [userData]);

  return <p onClick={handleDelete}>X</p>;
};
```

This is the same issue as posted in [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)